How does server-sent events check for updates server-side and scale?
I'm a little confused about how server-sent events are meant to scale with multiple concurrent users.
For some context, I wrote an MMORTS (Massively Multiplayer Online Real Time Strategy game) years ago that works just fine. It uses the LAMP stack exclusively on the back end (JavaScript on the front end), and can handle a reasonable number of concurrent players using AJAX long polling. It has worked well, but I'd like to scale it up now as much as possible. My requirements are not to use any other core technology (e.g. nodeJS, NGINX, mongoDB etc. even though I know they can do this) because I don't want to spend a lot of time and effort in re-writing large chunks of the architecture.
I have successfully created a basic SSE proof of concept for all of the stuff my game needs to do, e.g. allow users to connect to the server, send back events when received etc. But I'm really struggling with one aspect: how on earth do you get each individual SSE script to know that an event has occurred?
Every bit of research I've done on SSE (including questions on this site) just abstracts away this problem and says "just get the SSE script to check a database or something". For example:
How do server-sent events actually work?
In the comments, people are repeatedly asking the same question that the OP wanted to know: how exactly do you get SSE to check that there's been an update server-side? And importantly, how do you do it so it can scale? Here's another one asking the same fundamental question:
Server-sent events and php - what triggers events on the server?
And again, in the comments people are not-so-helpfully saying "roll your own", although the first answer starts getting a little closer to the solution by suggesting polling an intermediary. This is what I am doing. Let's assume there are 10 players connected concurrently and the event loop is one second:

Client(s) connects to sse.php script(s)
sse.php script(s) run event loop that checks to see if there has been a database update

So what, there are 10 database queries every second for exactly the same thing? What if there were 100 connected players?
Let's try that again, but this time let's stick in some way of getting database updates without n clients smashing the database:

Client(s) connects to sse.php script(s)
checkForUpdates.php runs in the background checking the database every second to see if there's been an update (this is the only script checking the database)
If there has been a database update, checkForUpdates.php dumps the update(s) into updates.txt
sse.php script(s) run event loop that checks to see if there has been an update to updates.txt
If there has been an update, sse.php script(s) fopen updates.txt (read-only), grab the update(s) and send them back to the client

I have tested this and it works very well, and looks like it can scale significantly because file reads are nearly instantaneous while each database connection takes a while. On my server, each database query takes ~150ms round trip, whereas opening a file 10,000 times takes much less than a second.
Am I missing something here? Is this the right way to do this, or is there a better way? How do other similar applications use SSE with the LAMP stack?
